# Are utm_source and utm_medium always required for link tagging in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, utm-tracking

According to every source I've found, in order to manually tag links for campaign tracking in Google Analytics 3 fields are required - `utm_campaign`, `utm_source`, and `utm_medium`. However, I get mixed results when I don't use the latter two.
If I set `utm_campaign` and `utm_source`, the campaign is tracked in GA with a medium value of `(not set)`. This seems to work dependably.

If I set `utm_campaign` in the href of an anchor tag on another site and leave out `utm_source`, the campaign source shows up as the referring domain when using the [GA debugging script](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingTroubleshooting.html#gaDebug) but no campaign name is listed nor does not seem to track properly when I look at the reports in Google Analytics. For example, if on www.referringsite.com i have an anchor that looks like 

`<a href="http://www.mysite.com?utm_campaign=test">click me</a>`
The debug tool will show `Campaign Source: referringsite` and the parameter `Campaign Name` is not listed.

What is going on here? When do I need to use these parameters and when can I leave them out? My ultimate goal is to allow the referrer to be used as the campaign source when `utm_source` is not explicitly set, and to leave `utm_medium` out altogether (which it appears I can do without issue). Can someone explain concretely what has to be used when and where, as well as how to achieve the desired effect of using httpReferrer as the implicit campaign source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`utm_source` is typically required if Google Analytics is to recognize *any* other utm parameters.

To set `__utmz` cookie (the one that contains source and campaign informations), analytics javascript first checks if a `utm_source` parameter exist. If not, the script passes through "standard" source setting and doesn't check other parameters like `utm_campaign`.

But you can achieve the desired effect with some javascript.

In your page, detect there is a utm_campaign parameter without utm_source.
You can use something like :

```
function isParameterInUrl(param){
    var url = document.location.href;
    var reg = new RegExp('(\\?|&|^)'+param+'=(.*?)(&|$)');
    matches = url.match(reg);
    if (matches[2] != undefined) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then set utm_source with :

```
var re_hostname = new RegExp('^(?:f|ht)tp(?:s)?\://([^/]+)', 'im');
var referrer = document.refferer;
_gaq.push(['_setCampSourceKey', referrer.match(re)[1].toString();]);
```

Be sure to insert your code before the _tackPageView call.

Comment: can you elaborate on the "standard" source setting you mentioned?

Comment: What I call "standard" source setting is the automatic extraction from the referer. (sorry for my response time)

Comment: so is it safe to assume `utm_source` is the only **required** parameter when expecting to use it with Analytics?